# Fullcalendar popup if more items is clipped on edges

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

Please see fiddle:
    [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xctthg9/9/)

If click on '+74 more' popup is clipped on right and bottom sides.
As I understand, this is because the popup parent container is DIV and this popup is rendered inside this DIV. 
Any ideas how to fix this clipped popup?
By the way, if uncommenting 'working popup' in CSS tab, fullcalendar adds a scroll, and popup is opened fine..

```
No Code Here
```

P.S. I have copied fullcalendar JS into SCRIPT tab, so there many lines there. Please, find actual calendar initialization inside this tab at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why but one of calendar div-s had

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Fixed that with:

```
div.fc-scroller.fc-day-grid-container{
overflow: visible !important;}
```

By now, didn't see any issues with this..